# How do I setup my own Postgresql DB as source to save o nfiles based on exisitng LDAP data in qwc-docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, postgis

I have error on qwc-docker app  `server process (PID 39) exited with exit code 2` while running `docker compose up` command.
What I had: qwc-docker base app with all services with base postgis configuration,
What I want: setup my own postgresql DB which contains users and their passowrds to log into and could use data and save it on each accounts in DB.

Using: docker-desktop, postgreSQL 15, WSL2

The full error code:

```
qwc-postgis-1                  | 2024-01-31 09:49:04.150 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
qwc-postgis-1                  | 2024-01-31 09:49:18.660 UTC [1] LOG:  server process (PID 52) exited with exit code 2
qwc-postgis-1                  | 2024-01-31 09:49:18.660 UTC [1] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
qwc-postgis-1                  | 2024-01-31 09:49:18.661 UTC [1] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
qwc-postgis-1                  | 2024-01-31 09:49:18.705 UTC [53] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2024-01-31 09:49:04 UTC
qwc-postgis-1                  | 2024-01-31 09:49:19.016 UTC [53] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
qwc-postgis-1                  | 2024-01-31 09:49:19.023 UTC [53] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/3907E08: wanted 24, got 0
qwc-postgis-1                  | 2024-01-31 09:49:19.024 UTC [53] LOG:  redo is not required
qwc-postgis-1                  | 2024-01-31 09:49:19.031 UTC [54] LOG:  checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate wait
qwc-postgis-1                  | 2024-01-31 09:49:19.074 UTC [54] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.015 s, sync=0.007 s, total=0.050 s; sync files=2, longest=0.004 s, average=0.003 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
qwc-postgis-1                  | 2024-01-31 09:49:41.770 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
dependency failed to start: container qwc-docker-qwc-postgis-1 is unhealthy
```

My service definition of qwc-postgis in `docker.compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  
  qwc-postgis:
    image: sourcepole/qwc-base-db:15 # 15 refers to the Postgres major version
    restart: always

    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ''
    volumes:
     - ./volumes/db:/var/lib/postgresql/docker
     - ./volumes/db:/volumes/db
    ports:
     - "127.0.0.1:5439:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -h db"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

my pg_hba.conf file is configured as:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256

# ldap configuration

host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       ldap ldapserver=10.0.0.4 ldapport=389 ldapbasedn="DC=dcname,DC=local" ldapsearchfilter="(name=$username)" ldapbinddn="CN=IT,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=dcname,DC=local" ldapbindpasswd="password_ldap"
```

The last file `pg_service.conf` that is important to share on that matter (as I think):

```
[qwc_configdb]
host=MY_DB_HOST1
port=MY_DB_PORT1
dbname=MY_DB_NAME1
user=MY_DB_USER1
password=MY_DB_PASSWORD1
sslmode=disable

[qwc_geodb]
host=MY_DB_HOST1
port=MY_DB_PORT1
dbname=MY_DB_NAME1
user=MY_DB_USER1
password=MY_DB_PASSWORD1
sslmode=disable
```

I have tried to anasyle the data from postgresql, there is table users which was premade in qgis schema and i imported my users there, I saw that users which somehow have information about encoding in field storing password havesome prefix about encoding (and i can log in that accounts, but some doesnt have (i imported data and it was like that and i cannot log in into this accounts) [postgreSQL example of encoding prefix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cl4X.png) I think it might be one of the ways to solve the problem and here my ideas to solve ends.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? The two config files you mention don't seem to be used in docker.compose.yml, so that connection isn't clear. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].